# Вывод wishlist в magento 2

Tags: php, magento

Как можно вывести wishlist всех пользователей в magento2?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать коллекцию вишлистов `Magento\Wishlist\Model\ResourceModel\Wishlist\Collection` без указания каких-либо фильтров, примерно следующим образом:

```
class WishListTest
{

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Wishlist\Model\ResourceModel\Wishlist\CollectionFactory $wishListCollectionFactory
    ) {
        $this->wishListCollectionFactory = $wishListCollectionFactory;
    }

    public function getAllWishes()
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Wishlist\Model\ResourceModel\Wishlist\Collection $wishListCollection */
        $wishListCollection = $this->wishListCollectionFactory->create();
        /** @var \Magento\Wishlist\Model\Wishlist[] $items */
        $items = $wishListCollection->getItems();

        return $items;
    }
}
```

Через вишлист у вас будет доступ и к конкретным товарам внутри него.